# GeoTrans p/invoke wrapper NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, c++, c#-4.0

I'm trying to expose methods I need to call from the GeoTrans c++ library but, am running into issues. Any help would be great!

I have the following c++ file that i'm running nmake against to compile into a dll.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "CoordinateConversionService.h"
#include "CoordinateSystemParameters.h"
#include "GeodeticParameters.h"
#include "CoordinateTuple.h"
#include "GeodeticCoordinates.h"
#include "CartesianCoordinates.h"
#include "Accuracy.h"
#include "MGRSorUSNGCoordinates.h"
#include "UTMParameters.h"
#include "UTMCoordinates.h"
#include "CoordinateType.h"
#include "HeightType.h"
#include "CoordinateConversionException.h"

using MSP::CCS::Precision;

int main(int argc, char **argv){}

extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall convertGeodeticToGeocentric(const double lat,const double lon, const double height, double& x, double& y, double& z)
{       
        MSP::CCS::CoordinateSystemParameters geocentricParameters(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric);
        MSP::CCS::CoordinateConversionService ccs( "WGE", &geodeticParameters, "WGE", &geocentricParameters );
        MSP::CCS::Accuracy sourceAccuracy;
        MSP::CCS::Accuracy targetAccuracy;
        MSP::CCS::GeodeticCoordinates sourceCoordinates(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geodetic, lon, lat, height);
        MSP::CCS::CartesianCoordinates targetCoordinates(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric);
        ccs.convertSourceToTarget( &sourceCoordinates, &sourceAccuracy, targetCoordinates, targetAccuracy );
        x = targetCoordinates.x();
        y = targetCoordinates.y();
        z = targetCoordinates.z();
}

extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall convertGeocentricToGeodetic(const double x, const double y, const double z, double& lat,double& lon, double& height)
{
        MSP::CCS::CoordinateSystemParameters geocentricParameters(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric);
        MSP::CCS::GeodeticParameters geodeticParameters(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geodetic, MSP::CCS::HeightType::ellipsoidHeight);
        MSP::CCS::CoordinateConversionService ccs( "WGE", &geocentricParameters, "WGE", &geodeticParameters );
        MSP::CCS::Accuracy sourceAccuracy;
        MSP::CCS::Accuracy targetAccuracy;
        MSP::CCS::CartesianCoordinates sourceCoordinates(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric, x, y, z);
        MSP::CCS::GeodeticCoordinates targetCoordinates;
        ccs.convertSourceToTarget( &sourceCoordinates, &sourceAccuracy, targetCoordinates, targetAccuracy );
        lat = targetCoordinates.latitude();
        lon = targetCoordinates.longitude();
        height = targetCoordinates.height();
}

extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall convertGeocentricToUTM(const double x, const double y, const double z, long& zone, char& hemisphere, double& easting, double& northing)
{
        MSP::CCS::CoordinateSystemParameters geocentricParameters(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric);
        MSP::CCS::UTMParameters utmParameters(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::universalTransverseMercator, 1, 0);
        MSP::CCS::CoordinateConversionService ccs( "WGE", &geocentricParameters, "WGE", &utmParameters );
        MSP::CCS::Accuracy sourceAccuracy;
        MSP::CCS::Accuracy targetAccuracy;
        MSP::CCS::CartesianCoordinates sourceCoordinates(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric, x, y, z);
        MSP::CCS::UTMCoordinates targetCoordinates;
        ccs.convertSourceToTarget( &sourceCoordinates, &sourceAccuracy, targetCoordinates, targetAccuracy );
        zone = targetCoordinates.zone();
        hemisphere = targetCoordinates.hemisphere();
        easting = targetCoordinates.easting();
        northing = targetCoordinates.northing();
}

extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall convertGeocentricToMGRS(const double x, const double y, const double z, char*& mgrsString, Precision::Enum& precision)
{
        MSP::CCS::CoordinateSystemParameters geocentricParameters(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric);
        MSP::CCS::CoordinateSystemParameters mgrsParameters(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::militaryGridReferenceSystem);
        MSP::CCS::CoordinateConversionService ccs( "WGE", &geocentricParameters, "WGE", &mgrsParameters );
        MSP::CCS::Accuracy sourceAccuracy;
        MSP::CCS::Accuracy targetAccuracy;
        MSP::CCS::CartesianCoordinates sourceCoordinates(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric, x, y, z);
        MSP::CCS::MGRSorUSNGCoordinates targetCoordinates;
        ccs.convertSourceToTarget( &sourceCoordinates, &sourceAccuracy, targetCoordinates, targetAccuracy );
        mgrsString = targetCoordinates.MGRSString();
        precision = targetCoordinates.precision();
}
```

I then have the following p/invoke calls in my c# class..

```
[DllImport("CoordinateConversionWrapper.dll")]
private static extern void convertGeodeticToGeocentric(double lat, double lon, double height, ref double x, ref double y, ref double z);

[DllImport("CoordinateConversionWrapper.dll")]
private static extern void convertGeocentricToMGRS(double x, double y, double z, ref char[] mgrsString, Precision precision);
```

Calling any of the above p/invoke methods results in a NullReferenceException. It seems like the issue is within the c++ code itself but, not being a c++ expert I'm not sure what the issue is...

Please Help!!

Comment: The issue might be that you probably forgot  to set the reference of Precision in convertGeocentricToMGRS. But this would not explain the exception for convertGeodeticToGeocentric

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to debug your code. You can enable debugging unmanaged code in the settings (Debug tab) of your C# project.

Please post also the calling code.

Remark: string output parameters for p/invoke are typically done with the StringBuilder class.

[EDIT] There is a problem with the string output - who provides the storage for the string and who is freeing it (if needed)? The only useful solution is to pass the storage (as char*) and the length of it into the C++ function. Use StringBuilder on the C# side as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I used the code you posted together with the latest version of the library and it works fine for me. One thing you might consider is wrapping as C++/CLI instead of using P/Invoke but this is another topic.

I am working under the assumption you are using Visual Studio 2010 (oh well one has to start somewhere :-) ).

One thing that is clearly not ok is:

**Native:**

extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall convertGeocentricToMGRS(const double x, const double y, const double z, char*& mgrsString, Precision::Enum& precision)

**and C#:**

[DllImport("CoordinateConversionWrapper.dll")]
private static extern void convertGeocentricToMGRS(double x, double y, double z, ref char[] mgrsString, Precision precision);

Do:

```
extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall convertGeocentricToMGRS(const double x, const double y, const double z, char** mgrsString, Precision::Enum& precision)
{
    MSP::CCS::CoordinateSystemParameters geocentricParameters(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric);
    MSP::CCS::CoordinateSystemParameters mgrsParameters(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::militaryGridReferenceSystem);
    MSP::CCS::CoordinateConversionService ccs( "WGE", &geocentricParameters, "WGE", &mgrsParameters );
    MSP::CCS::Accuracy sourceAccuracy;
    MSP::CCS::Accuracy targetAccuracy;
    MSP::CCS::CartesianCoordinates sourceCoordinates(MSP::CCS::CoordinateType::geocentric, x, y, z);
    MSP::CCS::MGRSorUSNGCoordinates targetCoordinates;
    ccs.convertSourceToTarget( &sourceCoordinates, &sourceAccuracy, targetCoordinates, targetAccuracy );
    int nMGRSLen = strlen( targetCoordinates.MGRSString() );
    ::CoTaskMemFree(*mgrsString);
    *mgrsString = (char *)::CoTaskMemAlloc(nMGRSLen + 1);
    strcpy( *mgrsString, targetCoordinates.MGRSString() );
    precision = targetCoordinates.precision();
}
```

Note that the char is passed in as pointer to pointer, and that CoTaskMemFree/CoTaskMemAlloc/strcpy are used (include Objbase.h for CoTaskMemAlloc)

And in C# code you can:

```
    [DllImport("MSPGeotransTest.dll", CharSet= CharSet.Ansi))]
    public static extern void convertGeocentricToMGRS(double x, double y, double z, ref string mgrsString, ref PrecisionEnum precision);
```

where:

```
 public enum PrecisionEnum : uint
    {
        degree  = 0,
        tenMinute = 1,
        minute = 2,
        tenSecond = 3,
        second = 4,
        tenthOfSecond = 5,
        hundrethOfSecond = 6,
        thousandthOfSecond = 7,
        tenThousandthOfSecond = 8
    }
```

Other possibilities probably exist to do this...

Some other useful things:

In order to be able to debug make sure that:

In Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Enable Just My Code" is unchecked.

In Project > Properties > Debug tab, "Enable unmanaged code debugging" is checked.

Place a breakpoint in the C# method and when the breakpoint is reached you can step into F11 and reach the C++ code...

I compiled the C++ Dll by choosing "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" (Configuration Properties\General\Character Set)

Also it would seem the CoordinateConversionService constructor throws a CoordinateConversionException if it is unable to load the configuration files (it searches them it would seem in a path that can be configured through an environment variable named MSPCCS_DATA and if the environment variable is not defined it looks for them in ../../data/ relative to the exe path).

Probably in the C++ wrapper methods maybe you would like to catch any exceptions that can be thrown by the called methods and return an error code... I.e. other situations that trigger exceptions is due to invalid input coordinates and so on.

As I said I have a working example so if you want I can send it to you...